# pyspark dataframe sum

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to perform the following operation on `pyspark.sql.dataframe`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import sum as spark_sum
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ('a', 1.0, 1.0), ('a',1.0, 0.2), ('b', 1.0, 1.0),
    ('c' ,1.0, 0.5), ('d', 0.55, 1.0),('e', 1.0, 1.0)
])
>>> df.show()
+---+----+---+                                                                  
| _1|  _2| _3|
+---+----+---+
|  a| 1.0|1.0|
|  a| 1.0|0.2|
|  b| 1.0|1.0|
|  c| 1.0|0.5|
|  d|0.55|1.0|
|  e| 1.0|1.0|
+---+----+---+
```

Then, I am trying to do the following operation.

1) Select the rows when column `df[_2]` > `df[_3]`

2) For each row of selected from above, multiply `df[_2] * df[_3]`, then take their sum

3) divide the result from above by the sum of column of `df[_3]`

---

Here is what I did:

```
>>> filter_df = df.where(df['_2'] > df['_3'])
>>> filter_df.show()
+---+---+---+
| _1| _2| _3|
+---+---+---+
|  a|1.0|0.2|
|  c|1.0|0.5|
+---+---+---+

>>> result = spark_sum(filter_df['_2'] * filter_df['_3']) 
             / spark_sum(filter_df['_3'])

>>> df.select(result).show()
+--------------------------+
|(sum((_2 * _3)) / sum(_3))|
+--------------------------+
|        0.9042553191489361|
+--------------------------+
```

But the answer should be (1.0 * 0.2 + 1.0 * 0.5) / (0.2+0.5) = 1.0
This is not correct. What??

It seems to me that such operation only taken on the original `df`, but not the `filter_df`. WTF?

Comment: Didn't you mean to do `result.show()`?

Comment: When I do` result.show()`, it gave me the following error: 

    Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`

Comment: Hah, I clearly do not know enough spark to answer this question (I don't even have the thing installed...)

Comment: Note that the `df` tag is for the Unix command by that name and has nothing to do with dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call it in filter_df.

```py
>>> result = spark_sum(filter_df['_2'] * filter_df['_3']) 
         / spark_sum(filter_df['_3'])
```

This is a transformation function which returns a column and gets applied on dataframe we apply it (lazy evaluation). Sum is an aggregate function and when called without any groups, it applies on whole dataset.

```py
>>> filter_df.select(result).show()
+--------------------------+
|(sum((_2 * _3)) / sum(_3))|
+--------------------------+
|                       1.0|
+--------------------------+
```